# Spacing (numwidth) control for listtheorems

Tags: table-of-contents, indentation, theorems, ntheorem

I am using the `\listtheorems` command from `ntheorem` to generate a list of theorems for a document. However, because I number the theorems inside sections, the theorem number is a bit on the long side, and when typeset the theorem numbers run into the theorem name.

I know that for lists of figures or the TOC I can control this using `tocloft` and setting `numwidth`, is there something similar I can do for the theorem lists generated by `ntheorem`?

---

MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[standard,amsmath]{ntheorem}
\setcounter{chapter}{11}
\setcounter{section}{22}
\setcounter{Theorem}{33}
\numberwithin{Theorem}{section}

\begin{document}
\begin{Theorem}[False Theorem]
This is not a theorem
\end{Theorem}

List of theorems:
\listtheorems{Theorem}
\end{document}
```

The output looks like:

[image: Colliding text]

Here's the tail end of the log from latex building the MWE:

```
** Generating table of Theorem
(./listthm.thm
Overfull \hbox (12.5556pt too wide) detected at line 1
\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 11.22.34 
 []

)
\tf@thm=\write3
\openout3 = `listthm.thm'.

 [1

] (./listthm.aux) )
```

Comment: A MWE is needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the following after loading `ntheorem`:

```
\makeatletter
\def\thm@@thmline#1#2#3#4{%
  \@dottedtocline{-2}{0em}{5em}{\protect\numberline{#2}#3}{#4}}
\makeatother
```

The usual definition has `2.3em` instead of `5em`; adjust until you're satisfied.

Comment: thanks, but unfortunately I hadn't realised that the fix would also depend on the fact that I am using `hyperref`. In any case, a suitable modification to the appropriate lines in `ntheorem.sty` patches the problem.

Comment: Yes, the macro is slightly more complicated, but it's sufficient to find its definition in `ntheorem.sty` and change the `2.3em` to the desired value.