# Spacing for \listtheorems in ntheorem

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref, indentation, theorems, ntheorem

**Q:** How do I get my theorem number and name to not overlap each other in my list of theorems?

This is basically the same question as ["Spacing control for listtheorems"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/43166/3762). But the solutions mentioned there still don't work for me. I've tried the following:

- egreg's `\makeatletter` solution
- minimizing package conflicts by eliminating some and re-ordering declarations
- a global search/replace of `2.3em` with `5.0em` in `C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.8\tex\latex\ntheorem\ntheorem.sty`

---

[image: listtheorems]

---

```
\documentclass{book}

% Original set-up
\usepackage[amsthm,thmmarks,hyperref]{ntheorem}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts}
\usepackage[bookmarks=true,bookmarksnumbered=true]{hyperref}

%% More minimal set-up (still doesn't work)            
%\usepackage[amsthm,thmmarks]{ntheorem}
%\usepackage{amsmath}

%% egreg's fix (doesn't work in my case)
%\makeatletter
%\def\thm@@thmline#1#2#3#4{%
%  \@dottedtocline{-2}{0em}{5em}{\protect\numberline{#2}#3}{#4}}
%\makeatother

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{model}[theorem]{Model}              
\setcounter{theorem}{100}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}

\begin{document}
  \theoremlisttype{allname}
  \listtheorems{theorem,model}
  \begin{theorem}[My Theorem title]
    My theorem text
  \end{theorem}
  \begin{model}[My Model title]
    My model text
  \end{model}
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. 
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8):

With `hyperref` loaded, quite a few instances of "2.3em" have to be replaced by a larger value. For convenience, I use the [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) package to do so.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[amsthm,thmmarks,hyperref]{ntheorem}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts}
\usepackage[bookmarks=true,bookmarksnumbered=true]{hyperref}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\thm@@thmline@noname}{2.3em}{5em}{}{}
\patchcmd{\thm@@thmline@noname}{2.3em}{5em}{}{}
\patchcmd{\thm@@thmline@noname}{2.3em}{5em}{}{}
\patchcmd{\thm@@thmline@name}{2.3em}{5em}{}{}
\patchcmd{\thm@@thmline@name}{2.3em}{5em}{}{}
\patchcmd{\thm@@thmline@name}{2.3em}{5em}{}{}
\makeatother

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{model}[theorem]{Model}              
\setcounter{theorem}{100}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}

\begin{document}
  \theoremlisttype{allname}
  \listtheorems{theorem,model}
  \begin{theorem}[My Theorem title]
    My theorem text
  \end{theorem}
  \begin{model}[My Model title]
    My model text
  \end{model}
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This does work on my larger example. Not the nicest looking since there's more space between theorems 1-9 and their titles than there is for theorems 10-99. I'll poke around in the `ntheorem` to see if I can get, e.g., theorem 1 to be numbered as 0.0.01.

Answer (score 4):

There's this very example in the documentation of the new package [`regexpatch`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/regexpatch); as lockstep says, more patches are necessary because the string `2.3em` appears three times in each macro to patch. All patches can be done in one swoop with

```
\usepackage{regexpatch}
\makeatletter
%\xpatchcmd*{\thm@@thmline}{2.3em}{5em}{}{} % not really needed
\xpatchcmd*{\thm@@thmline@name}{2.3em}{5em}{}{} 
\xpatchcmd*{\thm@@thmline@noname}{2.3em}{5em}{}{}
\makeatother
```

because the *-version of `\xpatchcmd` does a "replace all". This has also the advantage that it works also when `hyperref` is not loaded.

Comment: I used this code in place of @lockstep's and it did not compile. It didn't matter if I uncommented that one line of code either. The end of the message I received went as follows: `("C:\Program Files\MikTeX 2.8\tex\latex\exp13\13file.sty")) ! undefined control sequence. <argument> \ExplFileName  1.30 ...e}{\ExplFileVersion}{\ExplFileDescription}`

Comment: @brianjd You have to update your TeX distribution. The version of `expl3` present in MiKTeX 2.8 is too old.

Comment: :) You were right. (I'm in the middle of a large project and been hesitant about updating anything for fear of breaking stuff). What I did that fixed the problem: 1. uninstall `expl3`; 2. install `l3experimental`, `l3kernel` and `l3packages`; 3. uninstall `xpackages`.

Comment: With a [patched newtheoremstyle](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/86271/8992) I need exactly the opposite -- uncomment the first line, while the two others doesn't make any difference -- and the one gets then right spacning.