# Horizontal spacing issue in \listoftheorems using amsthm + thmtools

Tags: table-of-contents, indentation, theorems, amsthm, thmtools

I am using the command `\listoftheorems` with packages `amsthm` and `thmtools`. The problem is that the theorem's head and its optional title overlap. How can I make this space bigger to avoid overlapping?

---

Thank you all. I include an example below (maybe not minimal). I've tried `\makeatletter\thmt@listnumwidth{4.3em}\makeatother` but I get errors. Same thing with `\renewcommand{\l@theorem}{\@tocline{0}{3pt plus2pt}{0pt}{3.5em}{}}`. Any other clues? Should I try working with ntheorem instead?

```
%% LyX 2.0.0 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,english,titlepage, fleqn,numbers=noenddot]{scrbook}
\usepackage[osf]{mathpazo}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage{courier}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\rmdefault}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\pagestyle{headings}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\setlength{\parskip}{\medskipamount}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing
\usepackage[unicode=true,
 bookmarks=true,bookmarksnumbered=true,bookmarksopen=true,bookmarksopenlevel=4,
 breaklinks=false,pdfborder={0 0 0},backref=false,colorlinks=false]
 {hyperref}
\hypersetup{pdftitle={},
   pdfkeywords={music cognition, categorization, embodiment}}

\makeatletter

\pdfpageheight\paperheight
\pdfpagewidth\paperwidth

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}

\declaretheorem[style=remark, name={}]{Example}
\renewcommand{\theExample}{\bf{Def. \thechapter.\arabic{Example}}}

\makeatletter
\def\th@remark{%
\thm@headpunct{:}
  \thm@notefont{\bfseries\itshape}}
\makeatother

\makeatletter
\def\thmhead@plain#1#2#3{%
  \thmname{#1}\thmnumber{\@ifnotempty{#1}{ }\@upn{#2}}%
  \thmnote{ {\the\thm@notefont#3}}}
\let\thmhead\thmhead@plain
\def\swappedhead#1#2#3{%
  \thmnumber{#2}%
  \thmname{\@ifnotempty{#2}{~}#1}%
  \thmnote{ {\the\thm@notefont#3}}}
\makeatother

\newcounter{genero}
\setcounter{genero}{1}

\AtBeginDocument{
  \def\labelitemi{\normalfont\bfseries{--}}
  \def\labelitemii{\(\star\)}
  \def\labelitemiii{\(\cdot\)}
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\listoftheorems

\begin{Example}[Género musical \thegenero]\stepcounter{genero}

first example.

\end{Example}

\begin{Example}[Género musical \thegenero]\stepcounter{genero}

second example.

\end{Example}

\begin{Example}[Género musical \thegenero]\stepcounter{genero}

third example.

\end{Example}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: Perhaps this is related: [Spacing for `\listtheorems` in `ntheorem`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/53353/5764)

Comment: Does putting `\makeatletter\thmt@listnumwidth{4.3em}\makeatother` help? I'm not 100% clear which space you mean (and haven't looked at that code for a while either).

Comment: without an example, it's not clear what the file name is, but in the file from which the list of theorems is set, there are presumably lines like this: `\contentsline {theorem}{\numberline {1.1}{...}}{2}`.  if this is so, then redefining the command `\l@theorem` should do the job: `\renewcommand{\l@theorem}{\@tocline{0}{3pt plus2pt}{0pt}{3.5em}{}}` where `3.5em` is the width of the space provided for the "head".  (be sure to wrap this in `\makeatletter ... \makeatother`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply use

```
\renewcommand\thmt@listnumwidth{4.3em}
```

after loading `thmtools` (and enclosing it within `\makeatletter`, `\makeatother`). Here's your document with some modifications to the preamble (I change the order of packages loading and suppressed some redundant and suppressed some redundant `\makeatletter`, `\makeatother` pairs):

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,english,titlepage, fleqn,numbers=noenddot]{scrbook}
\usepackage[osf]{mathpazo}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage{courier}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\rmdefault}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\pagestyle{headings}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\setlength{\parskip}{\medskipamount}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage[unicode=true,
 bookmarks=true,bookmarksnumbered=true,bookmarksopen=true,bookmarksopenlevel=4,
 breaklinks=false,pdfborder={0 0 0},backref=false,colorlinks=false]
 {hyperref}
\hypersetup{pdftitle={},
 pdfkeywords={music cognition, categorization, embodiment}}

\pdfpageheight\paperheight
\pdfpagewidth\paperwidth

\declaretheorem[style=remark, name={}]{Example}
\renewcommand{\theExample}{\bf{Def. \thechapter.\arabic{Example}}}

\makeatletter

\renewcommand\thmt@listnumwidth{4.3em}

\def\th@remark{%
\thm@headpunct{:}
  \thm@notefont{\bfseries\itshape}}

\def\thmhead@plain#1#2#3{%
  \thmname{#1}\thmnumber{\@ifnotempty{#1}{ }\@upn{#2}}%
  \thmnote{ {\the\thm@notefont#3}}}
\let\thmhead\thmhead@plain
\def\swappedhead#1#2#3{%
  \thmnumber{#2}%
  \thmname{\@ifnotempty{#2}{~}#1}%
  \thmnote{ {\the\thm@notefont#3}}}
\makeatother

\newcounter{genero}
\setcounter{genero}{1}

\AtBeginDocument{
  \def\labelitemi{\normalfont\bfseries{--}}
  \def\labelitemii{\(\star\)}
  \def\labelitemiii{\(\cdot\)}
}

\begin{document}
\listoftheorems

\begin{Example}[Género musical \thegenero]\stepcounter{genero}

first example.

\end{Example}

\begin{Example}[Género musical \thegenero]\stepcounter{genero}

second example.

\end{Example}

\begin{Example}[Género musical \thegenero]\stepcounter{genero}

third example.

\end{Example}
\end{document}
```

[image]

On a side note, I find somehow odd that you load `thmtools` but apparently do not use all of its features as a front-end (or, at least that's the impression I got from a quick look to your code) to help you define your structures; perhaps, if I find some time, I will give you some suggestion about this also, but I can't promise anything.

Comment: I've tried it, but I get the following error: \thmt@listnumwidth undefined. In which file should I find this command?

Comment: @varun \thmt@listnumwidth is defined by thmtools. Do you have a recent version of the package?

Comment: Yes, I bet that's the problem. I work on ubuntu and I think that texlive2009 (not 2011) is delivered by default. I should install a newer version.

Comment: @varun Most probably... using TeX Live2011 my example code compiles OK. Do you also get the error with my simple document?

Comment: Yes, I also get the error with your example. I'll try TexLive2011.

Comment: @varun: then yes, installing TeX Live2011 it's the thing to do.

Comment: That's right. Everything working fine now with TexLive2011. Thanks.