# Align the names in \listtheorems (ntheorem)

Tags: table-of-contents, horizontal-alignment, theorems, ntheorem

**Question:**

How do I align the names of theorems in `ntheorem` list of theorems?

Screenshot: [image: Current output]

Screenshot: [image: Intentended output] (photoshopped)

**Context:**

I am using the `ntheorem` package to typeset a list of theorems and definitions (`\listtheorems`) and have defined several custom theorem environments. The environment names have different word lengths which leads to a non aligned typesetting in the list.

I am writing in German language in which only one environment name is significantly shorter altough noticable minimal meanderings exist between the others as well.

Screenshot: [image]

**Related Questions**
I have found two related questions but both focus only on spacing.

[TeX.SE Question: 53353 Titlespacing for \listtheorems in ntheorem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/53353/1860)

[TeX.SE Question: 43166 Spacing numwidth control for \listtheorems](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/43166/1860)

**Minimal Example:**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ntheorem}

\theoremlisttype{allname}

\newtheorem{axiom}{Axiom}
\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}
\newtheorem{converse}{Converse}

\begin{document}
\listtheorems{axiom,proposition,lemma,corollary,converse}

\begin{axiom}[Theorem 1] \end{axiom}
\begin{proposition}[Theorem 2] \end{proposition}
\begin{lemma}[Theorem 3] \end{lemma}
\begin{corollary}[Theorem 4] \end{corollary}
\begin{converse}[Theorem 5] \end{converse}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To solve this we need to patch `\thm@@thmline` in `ntheorem`.

It's called `\thm@@thmline@noname` or `\thm@@thmline@name` depending on the called options `all` or `opt` or, respectively `allname` or `optname`.

There are two versions of these macros in `ntheorem`. Those with four parameters are used in non-`hyperref` documents. Those with five parameters are used in documents when `hyperref` is loaded.

Therefore you can either patch `\thm@@thmline` directly and force `allname`/`optname` behavior like in the first code snippet or you can patch `\thm@@thmline@name` as in the second code snippet, which will preserve the ability to use `opt` and `all`. Both snippets will work with and without `hyperref`.

Solution 1

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ntheorem}

%\usepackage{hyperref}
%\usepackage[hyperref]{ntheorem}

\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{
    \@ifpackageloaded{hyperref}
     {
      % hyperref version of the macro
      \renewcommand\thm@@thmline[5]{%
        \@dottedtocline {-2}{0em}{2.3em}{\hyper@linkstart{link}{#5}{\makebox[\widesttheorem][l]{#1 \protect \numberline {#2}}#3}\hyper@linkend}{#4}%
      }
     }
     {
      % standard, non-hyperref version of the macro
      \renewcommand\thm@@thmline[4]{%
        \@dottedtocline {-2}{0em}{2.3em}{\makebox[\widesttheorem][l]{#1 \protect \numberline {#2}}#3}{#4}%
     }
```

}
       \settowidth{\widesttheorem}{Proposition 10\quad}
    }
    \makeatother
    \newlength\widesttheorem

```
\theoremlisttype{allname}

\newtheorem{axiom}{Axiom}
\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}
\newtheorem{converse}{Converse}

\begin{document}
\listtheorems{axiom,proposition,lemma,corollary,converse}

\begin{axiom}[Theorem 1]
\end{axiom}
\begin{proposition}[Theorem 2]
\end{proposition}
\begin{lemma}[Theorem 3]
\end{lemma}
\begin{corollary}[Theorem 4]
\end{corollary}
\begin{converse}[Theorem 5]
\end{converse}

\end{document}
```

Solution 2

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ntheorem}

%\usepackage{hyperref}
%\usepackage[hyperref]{ntheorem}

\makeatletter
\def\thm@@thmline@name#1#2#3#4{%
        \@dottedtocline{-2}{0em}{2.3em}%
                   {\makebox[\widesttheorem][l]{#1 \protect\numberline{#2}}#3}%
                   {#4}}
\@ifpackageloaded{hyperref}{
\def\thm@@thmline@name#1#2#3#4#5{%
    \ifx\\#5\\%
        \@dottedtocline{-2}{0em}{2.3em}%
            {\makebox[\widesttheorem][l]{#1 \protect\numberline{#2}}#3}%
            {#4}
    \else
        \ifHy@linktocpage\relax\relax
            \@dottedtocline{-2}{0em}{2.3em}%
                {\makebox[\widesttheorem][l]{#1 \protect\numberline{#2}}#3}%
                {\hyper@linkstart{link}{#5}{#4}\hyper@linkend}%
        \else
            \@dottedtocline{-2}{0em}{2.3em}%
                {\hyper@linkstart{link}{#5}%
                  {\makebox[\widesttheorem][l]{#1 \protect\numberline{#2}}#3}\hyper@linkend}%
                    {#4}%
        \fi
    \fi}
}
\makeatother
\newlength\widesttheorem
\AtBeginDocument{
  \settowidth{\widesttheorem}{Proposition 10\quad}
}

\theoremlisttype{allname}

\newtheorem{axiom}{Axiom}
\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}
\newtheorem{converse}{Converse}

\begin{document}
\listtheorems{axiom,proposition,lemma,corollary,converse}

\begin{axiom}[Theorem 1]
\end{axiom}
\begin{proposition}[Theorem 2]
\end{proposition}
\begin{lemma}[Theorem 3]
\end{lemma}
\begin{corollary}[Theorem 4]
\end{corollary}
\begin{converse}[Theorem 5]
\end{converse}

\end{document}
```

In the argument to `\settowidth` you put the longest label, the biggest number and a suitable spacing.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! :) I've added hyperref compatibility and an alternative which preserves options `opt` and `allopt`. The edit is in review at the moment. I hope it's okay to you :)

Comment: @Christoph I'll look at it; thanks for the addition.